# How to Force Disposal of Objects / GC

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, garbage-collection, dispose, out-of-memory

How do you force objects to dispose after use in order to free up memory? And, how do you force GC to collect?

Here's my Save Code. I've noticed that, every time I execute this function, my memory consumption goes up that would eventually caused an out of memory error after a couple of hits.

```
protected void btnSaveEmptyOC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    try
    {

        if (ViewState["ServiceDetailID"].ToString() != null)
        {
            CashExpense tblCashExpenses = new CashExpense();
            Guid CashExpensesID = Guid.NewGuid();

            tblCashExpenses.CashExpensesID = CashExpensesID;


            tblCashExpenses.ServiceDetailsID = new Guid(ViewState["ServiceDetailID"].ToString());

            tblCashExpenses.Description = txtDescriptionEmptyOC.Text;
            tblCashExpenses.Quantity = Decimal.Parse(txtQTYEmptyOC.Text);
            tblCashExpenses.UnitCost = Decimal.Parse(txtUnitCostEmptyOC.Text);
            tblCashExpenses.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
            tblCashExpenses.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            tblCashExpenses.CashExpensesTypeID = "OTHER";

            CashExpenses_worker.insert(tblCashExpenses);
            CashExpenses_worker.submit();
            //Clear items after saving
            txtDescriptionEmptyOC.Text = "";
            txtQTYEmptyOC.Text = "";
            txtUnitCostEmptyOC.Text = "";


            ValidationMessage.ShowValidationMessage(MessageCenter.CashExpenseMaintenace.InsertOC2, "SaveEmptyOC", this.Page);
            MyAuditProvider.Insert(this.GetType().ToString(), ViewState["MarginAnalysisID"].ToString(), MessageCenter.Mode.ADD, MessageCenter.CashExpenseMaintenace.InsertOC2, Page.Request, User);
            divOtherCost.Visible = false;
            grd_othercost.Visible = true;
            btnaddothercost.Visible = true;

            tblCashExpenses = null;
        }
        else
        {
            ValidationMessage.ShowValidationMessage(MessageCenter.CashExpenseMaintenace.SaveServiceDetailOC, "SaveEmptyOC", this.Page);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        ValidationMessage.ShowValidationMessage(MessageCenter.CashExpenseMaintenace.InsertOCError, "SaveEmptyOC", this.Page);
    }

    finally
    {
        //Rebinds the Grid
        populategrd_othercost();
        Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Here's My business layer class

```
public class CashExpensesBL
{
    CEADataStoreDataContext CashExpensesDB = new CEADataStoreDataContext();

    public IEnumerable<CashExpense> get()
    {
        return CashExpensesDB.CashExpenses;
    }
    public IEnumerable<CashExpense> get(Expression<Func<CashExpense, Boolean>> express)
    {
        return CashExpensesDB.CashExpenses.Where(express);
    }
    public void insert(CashExpense item)
    {
        CashExpensesDB.CashExpenses.InsertOnSubmit(item);
    }
    public void delete(CashExpense item)
    {
        CashExpensesDB.CashExpenses.DeleteOnSubmit(item);
    }
    public void deleteDC(Guid servicedetailid)
    {
        CashExpensesDB.sp_deleteDefaultCost(servicedetailid);
    }
    public void submit()
    {
        CashExpensesDB.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should dispose your `DataContext`. I can't see it being removed anywhere, so the connection will remain open and references may be held on to (preventing the GC from picking them up). This may be what's causing the problem. If you don't want to dispose manually, you can perform the transaction within a `using` block.

Edit in response to Business Layer update -

You can wrap the methods in `using` blocks like this:

```
public void insert(CashExpense item)
{    
   using(CEADataStoreDataContext CashExpensesDB = new CEADataStoreDataContext())
   {
       CashExpensesDB.CashExpenses.InsertOnSubmit(item); 
       CashExpensesDB.SubmitChanges();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, how can i dispose the datacontext?  i have a separate class on my business layer. ill add it in a while..

Comment: You can simply call the `datacontext.Dispose` method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.dispose.aspx

Comment: hi, i have added my business layer class. Kindly take a look at it thanks.

Comment: would this work?
 public void submit()
        {
            CashExpensesDB.SubmitChanges();
            CashExpensesDB.Dispose();
        }

Comment: You can update your other methods like above. Basically, you're opening the DataContext only when you need it, and closing it as soon as you don't need it. `Using` blocks will automatically call `Dispose` for you once the end of the block is reached. See if that helps fix the error.

Comment: hi, should I remove the CEADataStoreDataContext CashExpensesDB = new CEADataStoreDataContext(); on my first line? in my business layer? I tried adding using{} on the submit and insert, it caused my save button to not work.it is as if the new data wasnt save.

Comment: Move the `SubmiteChanges()` code into the actual method like I've done in my answer. This way, it runs with the same DataContext (before, the DataContext was removed before it got to the `submit` bit). Now try saving it. Yes, you can comment out the first line.

Comment: You're welcome :) See if it fixes your saving issue and the memory problem, otehrwise something else is causing the memory exception.

Answer (score 4):

Assign nulls to variables referencing your objects, the use `GC.Collect();` to force  garbage collection. You may need to call it twice in a row to speed non-accessible objects through the process.

Comment: tblCashExpenses = null; then il add GC.COllect() 2x? on my try block?

Comment: @anonymous1110 Yes, see if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Set the object to null, then call:

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Comment: This will not work, because a single GC.Collect() call just moves the object to the next generation. There is no way, to gurantee that that GC.Collect() even does something..